# Unity Character Movement bug, player building up momentum while standing still

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I am trying to create a movement controller for my 3D character in Unity. The character is accelerating slowly (as intended) and decelerating slowly (also intended). But when I run into a box, keep running and slowly move to the side, i will eventually shoot forward, as demonstrated in the video. I added a speed counter in the top left. 
https://youtu.be/q8JFRwqrujU

Below is the class that controls the players movement provided. The direction in the function *Move* comes from the InputAction: `movement.action.performed += ctx => playerMovement.Move(ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>());`

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController characterController;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI speedText;
    private Vector3 movementDirection;
    private Vector3 movementVelocity;

    [SerializeField] private float accelerationSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float decelerationSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed = 20f;

    private void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    public void Move(Vector2 direction)
    {
        movementDirection = new Vector3(direction.x, 0f, direction.y);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        movementDirection = Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (movementDirection.magnitude > 0)
        {
            Vector3 desiredVelocity = movementDirection.normalized * movementSpeed;
            movementVelocity = Vector3.MoveTowards(movementVelocity, desiredVelocity, accelerationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            movementVelocity = Vector3.MoveTowards(movementVelocity, Vector3.zero, decelerationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        Vector3 movement = transform.TransformDirection(movementVelocity) * Time.deltaTime;
        characterController.Move(movement);

        speedText.text = characterController.velocity.magnitude.ToString("0.##");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am also new in unity. But i think i can help you.
Write this in your movement scripts

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * horizontalInput * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * verticalInput *_speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: That would indeed make the player move but not accelerate slowly I think. And Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") is a bit outdated and can be replaced by the new InputAction system. If you take a look at the Move function, direction.x is the horizontalInput and direction.y is the verticalInput